# serializing only certain fields from a queryset in django serializer class

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a queryset which I obtain from `get_queryset()`. What we know is, the returns of queryset gives the list of objects which contains all the fields of the model. Now I don't want to serialize all the fields from the model and show all of them in the response. I want to serialize only few fields and show in the api response.

for eg:

```
def get_queryset(self):

    """""
        filtering happens here on the query parameters.
    """
    abc = self.request.GET.get('abc',None)
```

Now I have a defualt list function where I have to call serializer class only with the specific fields.

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    # data ={
    #     "name":queryset.
    # }
    
    # serializer = ExampleSerializer(data,many=True)
    #serializer = serializers.serialize("json",queryset=queryset,fields=['id','name','address'])        
    return Response(serializer, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I do print queryset it gives complex queryset and when I do `print(type(queryset))`,it gives the following

```
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

Now how to serialize name and address fields only to the exampleserializer class?? I did some digging and tried to do the following

```
#serializer = serializers.serialize("json",queryset=queryset,fields=['id','name','address'])
```

but it does not give the output in the required format not like regular json. Also it gives model: Example in the response of every object.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```py
queryset = self.get_queryset().values('name', 'address')
```

Comment: I GET the values but cant serialize the queryset. I did as you said but got error Exampleserializer is not json serializable.

Comment: Your serializer also should have just name and address fields. If there are another fields at your serializer, you will get error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you are trying to fetch as your code is incomplete, but it seems that what you need is a [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer).
`get_queryset()` should be used to retrieve a queryset of objects that will be used by the serializer thanks to DRF inheritance & mixins system:

```py
# Serializer
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'address')

# View
class ExampleList(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Example.objects.filter(...)
```

Comment: I am trying to serialize only certain fields and show in api response for eg id and name. I am using the serializer class for create as well. so I hope you get my point.

Comment: @Django-Rocks that's exactly what my code does, but it requires `get_queryset()` to return a "true" django queryset (meaning a queryset of Model objects). What does yours returns? Could you add the entire function please?

Comment: yes, it returns the queryset `Example.objects.filter(name=name).order_by('-created_at')` . Now I dont want to create a separate serializer class consisting of only certain fields as you suggested

Comment: I'm not sure why you would not do it that way as it is the recommended one, but as said by Onur, you can do something like `return Response(data=list(self.get_queryset().values('id', 'name', 'address')), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`

Comment: Hello @Thomas `return Response(data=list(self.get_queryset().v` you dont seem to serialize the queryset. How is this working?? I am confused?

Comment: What's the error?